# Multiple Instances of the same WPF Window and ViewModel

Tags: wpf, window, multiple-instances

I have a window named 'winAppt.xaml' and a view model called 'ItemViewModel.vb'.  I would like the user to be able to open multiple instances of the 'winAppt.xaml' window to show different accounts on the screen at once.  Problem right now is that when the second instance of 'winAppt.xaml' loads the first instance has some of it's data replaced with the second instance.

I'm currently doing something like this

```
Dim i As New ItemViewModel()
i.Load(itemID)
Dim fDetailRec As New winAppt(i)
fDetailRec.ShowDialog()
```

I then set the DataContext of my window to the view model passed in.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal i As ItemViewModel)
    Me.DataContext = i
End Sub
```

Comment: You are creating new instances of the ViewModel and View so nothing should be shared...perhaps a portion of code is missing that is causing the behavior? Can you provide additional code around the construction of the ViewModels/Views?

Comment: Thanks, you confirmed to me that my direction was correct and I was able to find a shared reference to a public model class that was referenced by the view model I was creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a shared reference to a class inside the view model.  This class was declared in a module and persisted throughout the application.  This class contained a list that I thought I was passing to my ViewModel, it was really referencing it.